# UX advice on Interview experiences listing page

Tags: page-layout

I have a site that has all career related stuff. I am adding a interview experience section now.

I have the following 2 idea in mind, but a little confused over what will be a better ux/seo and easier for users(mostly students and a few experienced professionals) to use it.

### Approach 1

One page for each company. And each page will have multiple entries like as shown below.

[image: mockup]

### Aproach 2

One page for each entry, for example for each of the above listed 3 experiences

- ABC - Soft Dev- 2004 Fresher by Anon
- ABC - DBA - 2009 3yr exp by Satish
- ABC - DBA - 2009 3yr exp by Rob

3 seperate page for them.

I am very confused how to present them. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should try **CARD Layout**.

[image: Card Layout]

- Makes easier to skim past posts.
- Browse/Glance by Employer and Position
- Experience takes up different visual space
- Posted by being the least important information comes last.

This would allow you to pack around 4 posts in one row to start with without lot of cognitive load when browsing multiple postings.

Comment: Wow ! love this idea.

Comment: Would share the implementation soon. Using angular for this :)

Comment: wot should i fill the center part with ? company logos ?

Comment: You should add description in the center part with a read more link at the bottom.

Comment: I created one using image. Here check this out - http://careerbaba.in/interview-experiences/

Comment: Looks good. I'd suggest having some more emphasis on Type, font-weight etc

Answer (score 0):

How you link to these pages is more important for the experience than how you set them up.

For example, if you have a feed of Interview Experiences that constantly refreshes, it will encourage users to check back more often to read newer entries. You could also have a "Random" or "Shuffle" button that presents the user with an account at random.

**You have two key objectives here:**

1. Promote multiple interview accounts at the same company
2. Promote similar interview accounts for the same job title/description

I would personally prefer the first approach of combining all the experiences at a company on one page and anchoring the user to the specific job entry once they click on it. I say this because some parts of company interviews tend to be similar and showing them all on one page would provide a more cohesive overview of what it's like to interview for a company. This would fulfill objective 1.

For objective 2, I would recommend having a link on each interview account that says something like, "Read other Software Dev interview experiences"

Answer (score 0):

For the first approach i would use just the headers in a list (one page per company), maybe with a short excerpt of the following detailed description. Provide some sort functionality (initially sorted by date, the most recent ones on the top). Looking for real-world examples, i would refer the google search results.

The reasons are twofold:

1. To reduce cognitive load: Headers with the interesting bit of information (when, who, maybe a rating) give me a clue, if i want to read the details. So i have a broader overview of all entries and i'm able to have a clue of the overall impression, than just read the first 2 entries and leave after that.
2. See the e.g. amazon reviews. There is a summary on the top with the ratings, if you want to go deeper (because there are bad ratings and you're curious), you can read the first/last entries and have the option to "See all 7.134 entries..." via link.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail? You've only said what you would do, but you've not said *why* you'd do it. The 'why' is the more important part there.

Comment: Ok, the why (sry i was in hurry):
1) To reduce cognitive load: Headers with the interesting bit of information (when, who, maybe a rating) give me a clue, if i want to read the details. So i have a broader overview of all entries and i'm able to have a clue of the overall impression, than just read the first 2 entries and leave after that.

2) See the e.g. amazon reviews. There is a summary on the top with the ratings, if you want to go deeper (because there are bad ratings and you're curious), you can read the first/last entries and have the option to "See all 7.134 entries..." via link.

Comment: I've added your comment into your answer instead of leaving it as a comment. If you want to amend it you can [edit] the post again to make changes. Better to keep useful answer comment in the answer text itself rather than in separate comments that may not get read.